# Keep getting Duplicate entry error when trying to insert rows into mysql database

Tags: c#, sql

would appreciate guidance on how I can insert data into a database. I am taking the values from an SQL database and inserting them into a MYSQL database.

This is how I am doing it.. But I keep getting Duplicate Entry error. Please can you advice what I am doing wrong? or suggest a better way to do it?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
string strSQL = SELECT Name, Account Number FROM customers;
SqlCommand icmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
SqlDataReader ids = icmd.ExecuteReader();

while (ids.Read())
{
    string customername = ids["Name"].ToString();
string customerAcc = ids["AccountNumber"].ToString();
MySqlConnection conns = new MySqlConnection
    string strMySQL = insert into customer(CusName, CusAcc) Values('" + customername + "','" + customerAcc + "' )";
    MySQLCommand icmds =  New MySQLCommand(strMYSQL, conns)
    MySQLReader reader =  icmds.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: You are inserting always the same _patientid_ and _patientvisitid_ for each loop on the sql reader (not _customername_ and _customerAcc_). And by the way. Look at how parameterize your queries

Comment: If you don't provide code that would compile it is hard to know what you are actually running and that makes helping you a guessing game.

Comment: @Steve, I think thats the issue I am having. How do I insert the other rows? Please can you advice?

Comment: @Crowcoder, this is the exact code minus the connection values, I think I am doing it wrong when trying to insert multiple rows

Comment: @EricDavid strings are surrounded by quotes so `strMySql` would be a syntax error. Also `new MySqlConnection` is an error. It may be an simple copy/paste error but we can't have confidence we are giving good advice if we can't be sure that is exactly your code.

Comment: You can move MySqlConnection outside of the while loop

Answer (score 1):

The error message is triggered when your database table has an unique index on one or more column and you try to add a value that is already in your table columns. Of course this is a design decision and you need to understand if you really need to have an unique index on those columns. If you don't need them then you can remove them with your administrative tool for MySql.

After saying that you need to follow a different approach when you handle a database task. The most important thing is to use always parameterized queries. These queries helps the database engine to optimize data access, avoid sql injection and simple parsing errors. The second most important thing is to close and dispose your connections as soon as possible to free resources on server and on client.

Here a possible solution to your code problems, I have commented the lines to highlight the good practices to follow when you handle a database task.

```
// Always enclose the connection objects in a using statement to free resources
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(.....connectionstringhere....))
{
    conn.Open();
    string strSQL = "SELECT Name, Account Number FROM customers";
    SqlCommand icmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
    SqlDataReader ids = icmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Prepare the MySqlConnection, as above inside a using statement
    using(MySqlConnection conns = new MySqlConnection(....as above....))
    {
         conns.Open();

         // Prepare the command only once outside the inner loop and use parameters
         string strMySQL = @"insert into customer(CusName, CusAcc) 
                             Values(@name, @acc)";
         MySQLCommand icmds =  New MySQLCommand(strMYSQL, conns)
         icmds.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
         icmds.Parameters.Add("@acc", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
         while (ids.Read())
         {
              // At each loop set the parameters new values and execute the command
              // Note that I use the values extracted at each loop from the 
              // SqlDataReader
              icmds.Parameters["@name"].Value = ids["Name"].ToString();
              icmds.Parameters["@acc"].Value = ids["AccountNumber"].ToString();
              icmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

    }  // Here the MySqlConnection is closed and disposed
} // Here the SqlConnection is closed and disposed
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if composite unique index has been created for columns *CusName* and *CusAcc* on table *customer*. In that case MYSQL prevents to insert duplicate row.

You can read more about this [Using MySQL UNIQUE Index To Prevent Duplicates](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/)